Numbers setting to hide the formatting bar by default
Every time I open a document in Numbers.app, the formatting bar is open. I have never used it, and always close it. I would like it to be closed by default when opening a new document.
I see a setting to hide this by default, but changing the setting does nothing. Any tips? Is this just some vestigial lefter setting that was removed?
sbarnum@Sam AngularJSConverter % defaults read com.apple.iWork.Numbers LSDefaultsShowFormatBarSetting        
1
sbarnum@Sam AngularJSConverter % defaults write com.apple.iWork.Numbers LSDefaultsShowFormatBarSetting -bool false
sbarnum@Sam AngularJSConverter % defaults read com.apple.iWork.Numbers LSDefaultsShowFormatBarSetting             
0

Quitting and reopening a document, the formatting bar is still, unhelpfully, there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
